# MessageReceivedAsync calls without argument

Tags: botframework, bots

I have this very basic question about calls to MessageReceivedAsync. I understand this method is called from context.Wait. However, what I want to clarify is how is the function called without passing on any arguments. 
The method definition has 2 arguments.

```
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    { 
    var activity = await result as Activity;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rahul,
this is actually a somewhat complicated question. I'll try to explain as best I can and point you to the code you can examine to get a deeper understanding if you desire.

context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync) is calling the Wait method of the IDialogContext which is defined as..

```
 public static void Wait(this IDialogStack stack, ResumeAfter<IMessageActivity> resume)
```

As you can see, this is an extension method of IDialogStack. The important thing to see here is the second parameter ResumeAfter. ResumeAfter is a delgate for what to do when the Wait event occurs, which is usually someone typing a new message to your bot.

Ok, now we can look at the definition of the delegate ResumeAfter. It is defined as...

```
public delegate Task ResumeAfter<in T>(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<T> result);
```

and there's your answer. The parameters for MessageReceivedAsync are a result of the delegate ResumeAfter. The values of the parameters are defined by and setup by the bot framework.
I hope this gave you a better understanding of what's happening behind the scenes with a MS bot.
This code is all contained on GitHub in [Microsoft's BotBuilder source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp)
The specific code file I'm references is IDialogContext.cs located [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/IDialogContext.cs).